# bootstrap 3.0 responsive 5 images in one row

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a problem with bootstrap 3.0 making 5 images in one Row and make those responsive ?
The grid system is based of 12 , so how to make 5 images and they look centered without any spaces ?

Also is there away I can make when viewed on tablets or smartphones <480 px  to be 2 images per raw? right now it shows 5 images under each other??

here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2">
 <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img1.jpg" />
 </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img2.jpg" />
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
 <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img3.jpg" />
 </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img4.jpg" />
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img4.jpg" />
 </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am using    col-md-2  Along with     img-responsive?  but its not working really because its not centered

Answer (score 11):

You could have an empty column on either side:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img1.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img2.jpg" />
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img3.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img4.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img4.jpg" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean add an offset?

Comment: Yes, you would offset the first col-md-2 in order to add an empty column. You don't need to do anything to add an empty column on the right side. So you now have 2 empty columns plus 10 (5*2) columns worth of images, = 12.

Comment: I see your point , but now for the 5 images I have spaces on both sides how can I get ride of those and make it fit 100%

Comment: This is probably the cleanest out of the box solution. I expect that any other solution will require custom CSS, at which point, the problem no longer has anything to do with bootstrap.

Comment: @user3150060 I know this comment might bug the perfectionist within, but what's wrong with a little bit of extra space on the right and left on larger screens?

Comment: thats fine with me but i have my images with 250 px width and they look kinda small to me on like a 1024 px width

Comment: If you don't want any space on the sides, you will need to write some CSS as @JeremyCook mentioned. This is extremely simple, it would just be something like .your-column { width: 20%; float: left; }

Comment: what about making it with smaller screens to drop down to two images in a row is that possible? right now they all show under each other

Comment: Yes, if still using bootstrap you could add the .col-xs-6 class. This will make them 50% width on small screens.

Comment: add it where? in my columns?

Answer (score 8):

To answer your other question:

> Also is there away I can make when viewed on tablets or smartphones
>   <480 px to be 2 images per raw? right now it shows 5 images under each
>   other??

The answer is yes.  Out of the box, using col-xs-6 in addition, you'd get 2 images per row for all viewports less than **768px**.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img1.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img2.jpg" />
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img3.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img4.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/img4.jpg" />
 </div>
</div>
```

If you wanted to customize Bootstrap via LESS, SASS or using the customizer here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, you could certainly adapt both the grid columns and the breakpoints.  What I mean by this, is that **you can make a 10 column grid or a 5 column grid and if you prefer to have your xs breakpoint at 480px, you can do that too.**

To do that you'd need to edit the grid system values: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system and the http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints

It's still Bootstrap with all its goodness, it's just a custom version for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a column class (I called it `col-sm-5cols`, but call it whatever you like), with styling just like Bootstrap's existing columns, and then give it 20% width when at the right size, via media query.

```
.col-sm-5cols{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-sm-5cols {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

**Example: http://www.bootply.com/YpKhYwVqfD**

And to get your 2 column setup on mobile, you can use `col-sm-6` to get close, or again customize a smaller columns with media query at 480px and `width:50%`

Comment: I was wondering if I add an extra raw to make it 15 images , how can I make it in smaller screen to be 3 in a raw?

Comment: col-sm-4. That's in the bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed. But in short, it's all based on a 12 column grid, and the # (col-sm-#) is the divider - so 12/4 = 3.